# Unallocated Space after BootCamp not restored to main HD

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, apfs

I am unable to reclaim 1 TB of Unallocated Space to my main HD. Neither Disk Utility or BC-Assistant succeeds in restoring it to a single partition.

[image: Disk utility error message]

The underlying issue (after running sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0) seems to be the following:

[image: Output of: sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0]

[image]

[image: Disk Utility unallocated space]

The process starts and fails, please is there anyway to get my 1 TB back to my main HD?

I cannot see the 1 TB Unallocated Space in 'diskutil list':

[image: diskutil list output]

Please, can someone explain what needs to be done to get the 1 TB back? My main HD is a fusion drive and should be 2 TB.

Output of diskutil info disk1s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset

[image: Output of diskutil info disk1s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset]

**Terminal**: sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0
gives exactly same error as **Disk Utility** when it fails.

Please, help me. How can I resize the container back to 2 TB and get the Unallocated Space left from the now erased former BootCamp partition that BC-assistant/DiskUtility cannot re-allocate back?

Comment: Did you run First Aid from within Disk Utility to check and fix the error?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for input - Yes I have tried Disk Utility, it fails when select the (-) to merge the Unallocated Space with my main HD. I have also tried to check and fix error within Disk Utility. I am wondering if this has something to do with me having to run sudo gpt -vv -r and finding where the empty space is, then somehow allocate it to a partition. (Btw you the founder of Driveinfo?, just tried downloading it)

Comment: You don't need `gpt` or `driveinfo`. You can get same information by entering `diskutil info disk1s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`

Comment: I ran the command and updated my question with the output. I wish I knew what to do know with the information? Can you please guide me further?

Comment: The command should be `sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0`. If does not work, you can try restarting the Mac and seeing if the output from `diskutil list` has changed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried the command and have updated my question with the output. It gives the same error ask Disk Utility when it fails. warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 242, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan file extents (id 242, size 945913856) "error found file extent (id 242) at logical address beyond the end of the dstream.  It then undoes all changes: A problem occurred; undoing all changes
Modifying partition map
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures

Comment: I do not know what caused the problem you are having. Nor, do I know how to fix your problem. It is possible your APFS container was corrupted before trying using the Boot Camp Assistant and you just did not notice until now.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I installed 'NTFS for Mac' to be able to write to the BootCamp Drive while logged in to OSX. I created a folder in my BootCamp-Drive where I dragged over some files from OSX. BootCamp was working after this. But after a few reboots and a Catalina update, and removing NTFS For Mac and subsequently opening BC-Assistant to restore the partition gave all the errors. Could NTFS for Mac have messed something up? What can I do to restore things to normal?